# select all data of date between the given date in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

i am trying to select all the data of month 5 from my table 
using the query

```
SELECT cout.badgenumber,cout.Checktime FROM CHECKINOUT cout 
inner join userinfo ui on(ui.userid=cout.userid)  
WHERE cout.Checktime between #05/01/2017# and #05/31/2017# 
and ui.badgenumber='1021'
```

and

```
SELECT cout.badgenumber,cout.Checktime FROM CHECKINOUT cout 
inner join userinfo ui on(ui.userid=cout.userid)  
WHERE cout.Checktime>#05/01/2017# and cout.Checktime<=#05/31/2017# 
and ui.badgenumber='1021'
```

but both gives data excluding the data of 31

when i try to use 32 in between date as

```
 SELECT cout.badgenumber,cout.Checktime FROM CHECKINOUT cout 
    inner join userinfo ui on(ui.userid=cout.userid)  
    WHERE cout.Checktime between #05/01/2017# and #05/32/2017# 
    and ui.badgenumber='1021'
```

syntax error in date query expression error comes

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-AEA83B3B-46EB-43DD-8689-5FC961F21762

Comment: this link might help..

Comment: Did you check in the db is data exists for 31 may?

Comment: i have tried but i am not getting data of particular date of 31 only

Comment: #Chetan Ranpariya i have data of 31 as well in the form
5/31/2017 4:38:05 PM
5/31/2017 7:29:47 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT cout.badgenumber,
       cout.Checktime
FROM CHECKINOUT cout 
INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON ( ui.userid = cout.userid )
WHERE MONTH( cout.Checktime ) = 5
  AND ui.badgenumber = '1021'
```

This answer uses the `MONTH()` function to extract a numerical representation of the month from the date passed to it and compares it to `5` (the numerical representation of `May`).

Please read https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Month-Function-78182042-7bf0-46e9-829e-c7012f773fc5 for more information on the `MONTH()` function.

If you have any questuions or comments, then please feel free to post a comment accordingly.

Comment: Just be aware that this will retrieve records from May of _any_ year ...